# Clip and create new pdf from existing pdf with page numbers as input - pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a pdf file with 10 pages, I need to clip the pages from 2 to 5 and create a new pdf. What I am doing is like the following:

```
PDDocument pddDocument=PDDocument.load(new File("sample.pdf")); 
PDFTextStripper textStripper=new PDFTextStripper(); 
String text = textStripper.getText(pddDocument).toString();
```

I am simply reading the pdf file and writing into a new file. How can clip with upper and lower bound as page numbers? Please guide me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution (for PDFBox 1.8.*) creates a PDF file with the contents like you asked for. Note that pages are zero-based.

```
    File originalPdf = new File("{File Location}");
    PDDocument srcDoc = PDDocument.load(originalPdf);
    PDDocument dstDoc = new PDDocument();

    List<PDPage> srcPages = srcDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

    for (int p = 0; p < srcPages.size(); ++p)
    {
        if (p >= 1 && p <= 4)
            dstDoc.addPage(srcPages.get(p));
    }

    dstDoc.save(file2);
    dstDoc.close();
    srcDoc.close();
```

If you want to work from the command line instead, look here:
https://pdfbox.apache.org/commandline/

Then use PDFSplit and PDFMerge.