# How to create a new pdf file and save it with PDFxStream

Tags: java, pdf

I use [PDFxStream](https://www.snowtide.com/) to cut pages and save as a new pdf file.

I know how to cut the pages, however I cannot find how to create a new pdf file and save it to the specified destination.

```
Document pdf = PDF.open("path");
List<Page> pages = pdf.getPages();

for (int i = 10; i < pages.size(); i++) {
    pages.remove(i);
}

// create a new file and save it

pdf.close();
```

Although I know other Java libraries, like Apache PDFBox, I would like to implement it with PDFxStream.

Comment: PDFxStream is a commercial software. So why not ask their support? You are either a paying customer or a potential future customer, that should be reason enough to answer you.

Comment: ... and if PDFxStream isn't the answer (it seems so), then look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27685890/535646

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that PDFxStream is the wrong tools for this task (saving new PDF documents) as it focuses on text and image extraction. I can't find any hint for such a feature in the technical documentation:

https://www.snowtide.com/help

Also your code didn't work when I tried it. The List-Implementation of the method getPages() obviously returns an unmodifiable list as the remove method throws an java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException